# How to return all employees in datatable beside tree grid departments

Tags: codeigniter, treeview

i'm new in CI and i have to create a tree-view for my project. This tree-view must display the list on departments and beside the number of employees of each department. I have created the tree view but my function return only one employee (the first) not all employees that works at that department. I have this function:

```
public function deptEmployees($dept_id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('department_id', $dept_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

How to modify that function to return all employees with the same department number? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`return $query->row();` is returning one row only, if there are more then 1 row, it shows the first result (as you experience)

you need to use `return $query->result();`

check the documentation on how to generate query results [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)